# Pushing SKB to the network stack

Tags: networking, linux-kernel

I have `net_device` which has the `ndo_start_xmit` function implemented.

When the `ndo_start_xmit` function is called I have an `skb` that contains the IP packet. I'll need to overt the packet with `IP+UDP` headers and send it back to the routing system.

The problem is that, when I call the `dst_input(skb)` or `dst_output(skb)`, I'll catch the `NULL` pointer dereference error. It seems that I can't use this functions to push the encapsulated packet into the network stack.

What is the solution?

Comment: SKB = [socket buffer](http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/skb.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to push an skb into the kernel stack, just use the netif_rx(skb) function.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. But how I can bypass the INPUT and the FORWARD paths?

Answer (score 3):

**During packet transmission (from driver to network link)**

Copy data from the socket buffer (skb->data) to the driver kernel buffer (inside the *hard_start_xmit* function).

**During packet reception (from network link to driver)**

Create a skb buffer.Copy data from the driver kernel buffer to the socket buffer and hand over to the kernel network stack using the netif_rx() function.